# Power Query - Fiscal Calendar 445 Current Month Week

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

I am trying to build a fiscal calendar in Power Query to provide this calendar as a dataflow for other departments too. In the past, I have used a DAX Calendar but this has its limits for sharing the calendar, right?
So, I already have the Date, Fiscal Year and ISO/ Fiscal week information, using this M-Script:

```
let
    StartDate        = #date (2009,1,1),
    EndDate          = #date (2024,12,31),
    ListOfDates      = List.Dates(StartDate, DurationDays, #duration(1, 0, 0, 0)),
    DurationDays     = Duration.Days (EndDate - StartDate) + 1,
    TableOfDates     = Table.FromList(ListOfDates, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    DateColText      = Table.RenameColumns(TableOfDates,{{"Column1", "Date"}}),
    DateCol          = Table.TransformColumnTypes(DateColText,{{"Date", type date}}),
    WeekdayCol       = Table.AddColumn(DateCol, "Weekday Number", each Date.DayOfWeek([Date], Day.Monday) + 1,Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Day Name" = Table.AddColumn(WeekdayCol, "Day Name", each Date.DayOfWeekName([Date]), type text),
    IsoWeekYearCol   = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Day Name", "Iso Week Year", each Date.Year(Date.AddDays([Date], 4-[Weekday Number])), Int64.Type),
    IsoWeekNrCol     = Table.AddColumn(IsoWeekYearCol, "Iso Week Nummer", each (Duration.Days(Date.AddDays([Date], 4-[Weekday Number]) - #date([Iso Week Year], 1 , 7 - Date.DayOfWeek(#date([Iso Week Year],1,4), Day.Monday)))/7)+1, Int64.Type),
    IsoWeekdayExtCol = Table.AddColumn(IsoWeekNrCol, "Iso Weekday Extended", each Text.From([Iso Week Year]) & "-W" & Text.End("0" &     Text.From([Iso Week Nummer]), 2) & "-"&  Text.From([Weekday Number]))
in
    IsoWeekdayExtCol
```

But how can I now add a column for the corresponding fiscal month and also a individual column for CurrentMonth and CurrentWeek.

How would you do that?

Comment: Is your final quarter also going to be 445?  Or will it be 454?  Does your fiscal year end on the **last** Saturday of the last month of the fiscal year?  Or on the **closest** Saturday to the end of the last month of the fiscal year?  What month is the last month of your fiscal year?

Comment: Thank you so much for your support @RonRosenfeld! It is a 445 calendar (446 for 2020). The last month is December. 2020 end is 03.01.2020, 2021 end is 02.01.2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a column with the corresponding fiscal month, you can derive it from the weeknumber (which you've already calculated). Since the months go 4-4-5, the associated month is predictable from the weeknumber.

```
   #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(IsoWeekdayExtCol, "Fiscal Month", each 
             if List.Contains({1..4},[Iso Week Nummer]) then "January"
        else if List.Contains({5..8},[Iso Week Nummer]) then "February"
        else if List.Contains({9..13},[Iso Week Nummer]) then "March"
        else if List.Contains({14..17},[Iso Week Nummer]) then "April"
        else if List.Contains({18..21},[Iso Week Nummer]) then "May"
        else if List.Contains({22..26},[Iso Week Nummer]) then "June"
        else if List.Contains({27..30},[Iso Week Nummer]) then "July"
        else if List.Contains({31..34},[Iso Week Nummer]) then "August"
        else if List.Contains({35..39},[Iso Week Nummer]) then "September"
        else if List.Contains({40..43},[Iso Week Nummer]) then "October"
        else if List.Contains({44..47},[Iso Week Nummer]) then "November"
        else "December")
```

By CurrentMonth and CurrentWeek I am assuming you mean an entire column filled with today's fiscal month and today's fiscal week.

You just need to add a lookup type of column, where you determine the row to return based on today's date. So:

```
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Current Month (fiscal)", each 
        Table.Column(#"Added Custom","Fiscal Month")
            {List.PositionOf(Table.Column(#"Added Custom","Date"),Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()))}),

    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Current Week (fiscal)", each 
        Table.Column(#"Added Custom","Iso Week Nummer")
            {List.PositionOf(Table.Column(#"Added Custom","Date"),Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()))})
```

Comment: Awesome, that works perfectly fine! How can I change the "Current Month (fiscal)" column into a Boolean with TRUE/ FALSE combined with the current fiscal year?

Comment: @joshua That's a different question than what you asked. But you should be able to do that with a simple `if .. then .. else` statement. Be sure to take both the fiscal month and the year into account.  You could either modify the `Current Month (fiscal)` column or create a new column.